# Using Schema_Object in GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator in Airflow

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I want to load GCS files written in JSON format into a BQ Table through an Airflow DAG.
So, i used the `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator`. Additionally, to avoid using the `autodetect` option, i created a Schema JSON file stored in the GCS bucket which i have my JSON raw data files to be used as `schema_object`.

Below is the JSON Schema file:

```
[{"name": "id", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},{"name": "description", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"}]
```

And for my JSON raw data file, it looks like that (New line Delimited JSON File):

```
{"description":"HR Department","id":9}
{"description":"Restaurant Department","id":10}
```

Here is my operator look like:

```
gcs_to_bq = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id=table_name + "_gcs_to_bq",
        bucket=bucket_name,
        bigquery_conn_id="bigquery_default",
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id="google_cloud_storage_default",
        source_objects=[table_name + "/{{ ds_nodash }}/data_json/*.json"],
        schema_object=table_name+"/{{ ds_nodash }}/data_json/schema_file.json",
        allow_jagged_rows=True,
        ignore_unknown_values=True,
        source_format="NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
        destination_project_dataset_table=project_id
        + "."
        + data_set
        + "."
        + table_name,
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        dag=dag,
    )
```

The error i got is:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse JSON: No object found when new array is started.; BeginArray returned false; Parser terminated before end of string File: schema_file.json
```

Could you please help me solving this issue?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I tried loading your csv by a console and it gave me an error that it cannot load the schema with the field name "description" as an Integer, So I changed to Int instead and loaded successfully. was the type intended to be an integer ?

Comment: Hello @NestorCenizaJr, Thanks for your reply. I fixed it and tried again, but didn't fix the issue unfortunately. WDYT?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems :

- Your `BigQuery` table schema is incorrect, the type of `description` column is `INTEGER` instead of `STRING`. You have to set it to `STRING`
- You are using an old `Airflow` version. In the recent version, normally the source object retrieves by default object from bucket specified in `bucket` param. For the old version, I am not sure about this behaviour. You can set the full path to check if it solve your issue, example : `schema_object='gs://test-bucket/schema.json'`

Comment: hello @Mazlum Tosun , thanks for your reply.  You're correct in the first point. For the second point, i think the error not related to the version of the Airflow as the error clarifies that it reaches the schema_object already but it cannot parse it due to finding ```[]``` in the .json file.
WDYT?